# how to make the file path to reach a file in specific folder of solution?

Tags: c#, filepath

I have some file path like below for reaching the file:

```
StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Projects\SisStuff\SIS\SIS.Core\Models\CreateEditTemplate.cshtml");
```

now I want to remove the c:Project\SisStuff part to make it independent from file path in my computer, I tries @"~\Models\CreateEditTemplate.cshtml" but goes to find it in debug folder, how can I make it work?

Comment: The working directory by default is the path to your exe file (which is probably why you get the debug folder). You can set the working directory in Visual Studio Properties (if that is the tool that you are using). Would that work?

Comment: BigM answer worked as I wanted and I didn't try this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this would be able to work across systems is to build a known system variable. For example, you can get the Windows directory by using `%windir%` right? Well that's because it's a well defined system variable.

However, if you're just trying to get to the root of your project you can remember that it is **always** going to start from the directory you're executing from. So, while running in visual studio you would want (assuming you're using the default path setup from the project templates) `..\..\Models\CreateEditTemplate.cshtml`.

However, if you needed this in production for some reason it would probably look more like `..\Models\CreateEditTemplate.cshtml` because by default there is simply a `bin` folder in production that you need to step up from.